# Projection onto set implies convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the finite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathbb{R}^N$ equipped with the scalar product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ that induces $l_2$-norm $||\cdot||_2$. Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\mathcal{P}_S$ be a projection onto $S$. That is

$\mathcal{P}_S(x)=argmin_{y\in\mathcal{S}} ||y-x||_2$.

Show that if $\mathcal{P}_S$ satisfies

$\langle z-\mathcal{P}_S(x),x-\mathcal{P}_S(x) \rangle \le 0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^N, z \in S$

then $S$ is already convex.

What I have tried so far:

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and $\tilde x = \lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$. Then:

$\langle z-\mathcal{P}_S(\tilde x), \tilde x-\mathcal{P}_S(\tilde x) \rangle \le 0$ $\forall z \in S$.

Fix $z=0$ and the inequality becomes

$\langle -\mathcal{P}_S(\tilde x), \tilde x-\mathcal{P}_S(\tilde x) \rangle \le 0$

$\langle \mathcal{P}_S(\tilde x), \mathcal{P}_S(\tilde x) \rangle \le \langle \mathcal{P}_S(\tilde x), \tilde x \rangle$.

And now I'm stuck. Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There's a little bit of trickiness here. Are we assuming $\mathcal{P}_S(x)$ is non-empty for all $x$? Or for some $x$? Is it supposed to be unique? Depending on your answers, I may have some counterexamples or proofs that don't rely on the inequality!

Comment: For example, $S = B[0; 2] \setminus B[0; 1]$ is a non-convex set where the inequality holds wherever $\mathcal{P}_S(x)$ is defined!

Comment: I came across that problem in a paper, so I'm not sure, but from what I can tell $\mathcal{P}_S$ is non-empty for all $x$ and not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(x, y) \in \operatorname{graph} \mathcal{P}_S$. Let
$$H_{(x, y)} = \{ z \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle z - y, x - y\rangle \le 0 \}.$$
Note that $H_{(x, y)}$ is closed and convex (and a half-space). I claim that
$$S = \bigcap_{(x, y) \in \operatorname{graph} \mathcal{P}_S}H_{(x, y)},$$
hence $S$ is closed and convex. Note that, from the inequality, we have $\subseteq$, so we just need to show $\supseteq$.

Suppose $w \in \bigcap_{(x, y) \in \operatorname{graph} \mathcal{P}_S}H_{(x, y)}$. Let $v \in \mathcal{P}_S(w)$. Then,
$$w \in H_{(w, v)} \implies \langle w - v, w - v \rangle \le 0 \implies w = v \in S.$$
Done!

Comment: Two questions: 1. H is convex, because for $a,b \in H, \lambda \in [0,1]$ we have $\langle \lambda a + (1-\lambda)b-y,x-y \rangle=\lambda \langle a -y,x-y \rangle+ (1-\lambda) \langle b -y,x-y \rangle \le 0$? and 2. Shouldn't it be $v = \mathcal{P}_S$?

Comment: Yes, $H_{(x, y)}$ is convex for this reason. As I say, $H_{(x, y)}$ is a half-space; it's everything on one side of a hyperplane, so it should be geometrically clear that it's convex. As for the second question, I write $v \in \mathcal{P}_S(w)$, because I prefer to do that for set-valued maps. Writing $v = \mathcal{P}_S(w)$ implies, in my mind, that $\mathcal{P}_S(w)$ has only a single value, i.e. $w$ projects onto only a single vector.